# Cartopy, set_extent with NorthPoleStereo not working

Tags: cartopy

Using set_extent on Polar Stereo Graphic maps doesn't seem to be working #in a predictable fashion. I am following this [Answered StackOverflow](https://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173159/central-longitude-#for-#northpolarstereo#new-answer?newreg=df2dcbbbee2b480dbfcf8fa10ca6e670][1]) example but neither rotation #yields a map. I have set `ax1.set_global()` to get the data displayed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
from cartopy.examples.waves import sample_data

# read sample data
x, y, z = sample_data(shape=(73, 145))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

# first plot with default rotation. Global extent, works fine

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
cs1 = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, 50, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                               cmap='gist_ncar')
ax1.set_title('Global')

#next plot setting extent to 0,360,40,90, no display 

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222,
          projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
cs2 = ax2.contourf(x, y, z, 50, 
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   cmap='gist_ncar')
ax2.set_extent([0,360,40,90],crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.coastlines()
ax2.set_title('Centred on 0$^\circ$ (default)')

#Now resetting set_extent to [-180,180,40,90] strangely works! 

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(
                     223, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
cs3 = ax3.contourf(x, y, z, 50, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                   cmap='gist_ncar')
ax3.set_extent([-180, 180, 40, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax3.coastlines()
ax3.set_title('Using -180,180 $^\circ$W')

#but now rotating projection yields just a corner of the map

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(
          224,projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=-45))     
cs4 = ax4.contourf(x, y, z, 50, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
               cmap='gist_ncar')
ax4.set_extent([-180, 180, 40, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax4.coastlines()
ax4.set_title('Rotated on -45 $^\circ$W')
plt.show()
```

I was expecting the set_extent to work as documented but there seems to be #a strange interaction between the rotation and the extent

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYGRY.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an artifact of how CartoPy calculates its bounding boxes. What it does, when given extents in lon/lat, is calculate the 4 corners of the box based on the extent, then project those to the native projection, then figure out the extent from that. The problem is that in the stereographic projection, some of those combinations end of up with no separation in x or y--due to the periodic nature of (especially) longitude.

I can reproduce the math issues with just PyProj, so it's not a problem with the projection math in CartoPy, just a limitation of how it calculates bounds. You can override by using projected coordinates in in `set_extent`:

```
ax.set_extent((0, 500000, 0, 500000), crs=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
```

I know that's not ideal, but I can't think of any good ways to calculate what the appropriate bounds is based on box in lon/lat space.